# FPDF - Variable not working

Tags: php, image, pdf, header, fpdf

I am trying to set the following image as a variable. 

 I get this error when accessing the pdf: **FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified:**

Here is my code:

```
$image1 = "../storage/$_GET[id]/01.jpg";

function Header()
{

$this->Image($image1,10,8,33);

}
```

anything wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you posted it's your actual code, try:

```
 $image1 = "../storage/{$_GET['id']}/01.jpg";
```

Please read **[here](http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)**;

Anyway, if `$_GET['id']` must be a integer value, it's better to avoid security issues using:

```
 $image1 = '../storage/' . intval($_GET['id']) . '/01.jpg';
```

Read **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php)** and **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)**.

Also, as *dev-null-dweller* said, global variables aren't visible inside functions. In that case, fix it using:

```
$image1 = '../storage/' . intval($_GET['id']) . '/01.jpg';

function Header() {
    global $image1;
    $this->Image($image1, 10, 8, 33);
}
```

And have a look **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is an actual code, but it looks like variable scope problem - `$image1` is not defined inside header function, so `FPDF` is trying to use empty string and fails as described in given error.